# Convergence in $L_{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and $E_n\in\Sigma$ such that $\mu(E_n)>0$, and we define $f:=a_n\chi_{E_n}$, where $a_n>0$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I want to prove that if $f_n\to 0$ in $L_{\infty}$ then there isn't $C>0$ such that $a_n\ge C$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

So, if there is $C>0$ such that $a_n\ge C$ for each $n$, I want to prove that $f_n$ doesn't converge to $0$ in $L_{\infty}$.

To do this, I want to find an $\epsilon >0$ such that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $\left\|{f_n}\right\|_{\infty}\ge \epsilon$.

Can you give me a hint to do this? Can we take $\epsilon = C$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $\|f_n,L^\infty\|=a_n$. If $f_n\to 0$ in $L^\infty$, then you have by definition $\|f_n-0,L^\infty\|\to 0$, hence $a_n\to 0$ and you can conclude.

Comment: In my own studies I've seen the $L^\infty$ norm denoted by $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{L^\infty}$ - is there any reason you don't use this notation? Or are you trying to achieve something else?

Comment: @DanZimm it's just a question of notation and of habit: my $\|f_n,L^\infty\|$ stands for your $\|f_n\|_{L^\infty}$. In general case, one of acceptable notations is $\|f,Y\|$ for "norm of $f$ in the normed space $Y$". Can come handy if you work with many different spaces at the same time.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy thank you :)